# How come iTerm is automatically moving a window when opening/closing new tab?

Tags: iterm2

What is the `iTerm` preference to automatically move a window when opening or closing a new tab?

I was playing around with different preferences, and now I got the behavior where when I open or close a tab in a window, it moves the window to the right of my screen.  How do I disable this?

Comment: Note that strictly, this question isn't on-topic, as iTerm usage and configuration is not "unique to software development" (as ANDed into other conditions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, making it necessary rather than sufficient). It would be a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [apple.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Profiles > Window > Settings for New Windows > Style > Normal
```

Instead of `Normal` style, I had selected `Full-Height Right of Screen`, which caused the window to move to the right side of the screen whenever I opened or closed a tab.

[image: screenshot of iTerm2 preferences]